# Найти все доступные для подключения пк

Tags: java, android, сокет

Пишу приложение для пк и телефона на сокетах. Сейчас при открытии соединения на пк показывается его ip/порт, а на телефоне я сам указываю ip и порт для подключения. Как сделать так, чтобы телефон сам находил все пк в одном wifi, готовые к подключению?

Comment: На компах на строго определенном UDP порту надо повесить процесс, который будет сообщать "я тут" и возможно дающий информацию о других портах к которым подключаться. С телефона посылать широковещательный UDP запрос на этот порт

Comment: @mike, а дальше проходить по всем компам и смотреть на этот порт?

Comment: нет. я же написал _посылать широковещательный пакет_. "Широковещательный" означает что вы его посылаете один раз а все компы в сегменте его видят и отвечают. Собственно для этого и нужен именно UDP, потому что он позволяет использовать широковещание. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB

Comment: да там все есть для этого. Смотрите в сторону WifiManager scanall devices, работа вроде идет с LocalDeviceInfo и ConnectInfo, Там что угодно можно сделать. Там есть проверки по инфам этим что доступен к подключению, можете по ip сверить, можно автоматически коннектить